# How to Get the Index of an Array Elemnt which Contains an specific String

Tags: javascript, jquery

having an array like

```
 var arr = ['best app in', 'Not q big deal', 'volvu is good-1',' volvu is good-0'];
```

how can I get the index and full text of the elemnt which contains exact match of `is good-1` in the array?

Comment: What issue are you having achieving requirement? Note, none of the elements of the array at the question contain the exact match `"is good-1"`

Comment: @Ele `.findIndex()` will only result in one part of the requirement.

Comment: `let index = arr.findIndex(s => s.includes("is good-1")); if (index > -1) {let string = arr[index]; console.log(index, string);}`

Comment: @Ele That is one possible solution. Though, again, given the input and strict requirement described at the OP, there should not be any output.

Comment: @guest271314 yes, the OP said exact match, it's ambiguous and a little unclear.

Comment: @Ele Unless "contains" is meant to only pertain to `"is good-1"` within the string, and "exact match" means only that part of the string to match, excluding the remainder. Would ``"notis good-12"`` still be considered to "contain" the "exact match" `"is good-1"`? What is the issue with OP's attempts in code to resolve own inquiry?

Comment: Just use [`.findIndex()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) method. To get element value use original array and the found index.

Answer (score 1):

Use the code below. I basically for looped through the array, and use `.includes()` to see if it had the `is good-1` inside it. If it did, I `console.log()` the index and full text. This code works if there is multiple strings with that value in your array. I added an extra value into your array to show that.

```js
var arr = ['best app in', 'Not q big deal', 'volvu is good-1', ' volvu is good-0', 'this is good-1'];

for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if (arr[i].includes("is good-1")) {
    console.log(`Index: ${i} Full text: ${arr[i]}`);
  }
}
```